# Git NOT SHOWING # Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit

Tags: git

When I modify any file, adding it to the staging area and the commit it to the local repository, I DO NOT SEE the message # Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit. when I type the git get status.
Any idea?

Regards,
R.

Comment: You'd have to give a bit more context I guess...

Comment: I would think this should not be happening.  Can you give an exact set of reproducible steps?

Comment: This is a very simple test project. a local git repository and a github private project and I am modifying some text file. all very basic. then I add a git add file.txt, and then a git commit -m "update". Then when I do a git status I do not see the message that my branch is ahead

Comment: Are you sure you can pull and push correctly? Maybe your remote is misconfigured?

Comment: Do a `git branch -vv` and make sure your local branch has correctly configured an upstream branch.

Comment: The github repo is private. Could this be the problem?

Comment: I have switched to public and still the same. I have created a new git project and a new github repo and I can see the warning. but not in the old one.

Comment: I can push to the remote and see the changes in github

Comment: Have you configured `status.shortt` to `true`? If so, try configuring `status.branch` to `true` as well, or use `git status -b`. (In any case, adding a text block to your question, showing the `git status` command and its output, may be helpful here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the -u flag when pushing to remote will display the status against the remote branch:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: same happened to me and this fixed